# How to rewrite loop to recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I implemented a search function and loop that search by collection. In first iteration I need to search by all collection, but all next iterations only by result of the first iteration. I use if-statement `if (i >= 1) collection = result;` to do it, but it's not safe because I need to save collection. Is it possible to rewrite loop to recursion function? How I can make it or make my code elegant?

```
var targets = target.split(' '); // => ['hello', 'world'];

for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
    if (i >= 1) {
        collection = result;
    }
    result = includes(collection, props, targets[i]);
}
```

My search function:

```
function includes(collection, props, target) {
    var result = [];
    var collection_length = collection.length;
    var props_length = props.length;
    var target_length = target.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < collection_length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < props_length; ++j) {
            if (collection[i][props[j]]) {
                if (collection[i][props[j]].toLowerCase().slice(0, target_length) === target) {
                    result.push(collection[i]);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result.length !== 0 ? result : false;
}
```

Comment: *"If it ain't broke, don't fix it!"*

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Yes, but it *is* broke: *"but it's not safe because I need to save collection"* (although I'm not sure I understand what he means by that).

Comment: What does *"but it's not safe because I need to save collection"* mean?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't get that part too. OP also stated that he wants it to be more "elegant" but to me it's elegant enough. :)

Comment: looks broken to me, if result is empty on any iteration, collection would be false on next iteration and includes function would fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = collection;
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
    result = includes(result, props, targets[i]);
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this what you're trying to do?

Comment: `var a = ['a', 'b']; var b = a; b[0] = 'x'; console.log(a) // => ["x", "b"]`. But I can clone without links, of course, but my collection can be big, with 5000 objects, and my function works a lot of times.

Comment: @BobNapkin `includes` doesn't modify the guts of `collection`.